# how to use ng content in nested component

Tags: angular

how to use ng-content in component nested?

modal.component.html:

```
<div class="body"> 
  <ng-content select="content"></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="footer"> 
<ng-content select="footer"></ng-content>
</div>
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>Hi</h1>
<app-modal>
  <app-user>
  </app-user>
</app-modal>
```

user.component.html:

```
<content>
  <h1>bodyUser</h1>
</content>
<footer>
<h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: your modal component doesn't know where to project app-user component  as there is no placeholder for it

Comment: how do i implementation this method?

Comment: the projection place holders need to be used where you use the app-modal component. <content> and <footer> need to be directly inside <app-modal>.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the given structure, you need to reconsider your component structures. Your modal component is expecting two contents but instead, you're passing down only the user component that wraps the content and footer tags. It will not work. You should pass user content directly to the modal component.

Answer (score 0):

With your current structure you can't use `ng-content` the way you're trying to use it because the `content` and `footer` elements that you're referencing with `select="..."` would need to be between your `<app-modal>` open and closing tags.

However, `<app-user>` is the only element between those tags, and is therefore `<app-modal>`'s only content child and the only element/component it can reference with `ng-content`.

**If you're open to alternative ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, though, here's one:**

What you can do is have `UserComponent` expose references to its `<content>` and `<footer>` elements using [View Child](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

```js
export class UserComponent  {
  @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('footer') footer: ElementRef;
}
```

With those exposed via the component class, `ModalComponent` can then reference its content child `UserComponent` instance using [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild):

```js
export class ModalComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ContentChild(UserComponent) userComponent: UserComponent;
}
```

Then `ModalComponent`, in its `ngAfterViewInit`, can access the `UserComponent` instance, and therefore the `content` and `footer` elements the instance exposes:

```js
export class ModalComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ContentChild(UserComponent) userComponent: UserComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const content = this.userComponent.content.nativeElement;
    const footer = this.userComponent.footer.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

With those elements in hand, `ModalComponent` just needs to insert them into its view.

One way to do that is to just create container elements for them in `ModalComponent`'s template, and assign template reference variables to them:

```html
<div class="body" #contentTarget></div>
<div class="footer" #footerTarget></div>
```

`ModalComponent` can then access those container elements using ViewChild, and append the `content` and `footer` elements into them. Here's what that would look like:

```js
export class ModalComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ContentChild(UserComponent) userComponent: UserComponent;
  @ViewChild('contentTarget') contentTarget: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('footerTarget') footerTarget: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const content = this.userComponent.content.nativeElement;
    const footer = this.userComponent.footer.nativeElement;

    this.contentTarget.nativeElement.appendChild(content);
    this.footerTarget.nativeElement.appendChild(footer);
  }
}
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8rursw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal.component.ts) showing this approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I gave the example of userComponent and anything can be inside the appComponent, how do we make it dynamic?

Comment: Maybe another component is here.

Comment: @ContentChild(UserComponent) userComponent: UserComponent;

Comment: @alito, it's not very clear just how dynamic you need it to be. If you haven't already done so, I recommend reading the [content projection documentation](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection). It contains examples for several different scenarios.